# How to add missing assets folder precompile to public/assets folder for Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I bought a html theme to use, in a Rails 4 project.
I have tried to compile assets in order to prepare for the production server.

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Also, I included this gem to fix my images digest name problem

```
https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets
```

But the problem is the CSS/fontello folder which that theme use as the icon was missing from the assets/public folder like this

[image]

The real folder contains the css folder like this: 
[image]

This is what i got from the browser console.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/assets/fontello/css/icon_set_2.css 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/assets/fontello/css/fontello.css 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/assets/icon_restaurant/css/icon_restaurants.css   
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/assets/fontello/css/icon_set_1.css 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/assets/icon_restaurant/css/icon_restaurants.css 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/assets/fontello/css/icon_set_2.css 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/assets/fontello/css/fontello.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

How can i fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Does it work in Development ENV ?

Comment: Development ENV is fine.

Comment: When running this: `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`, Do you see public/assets/fontello folder ?

Comment: @7urkm3n yes but the css is not there.